# Translation with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, gettext

I have a angulerjs / grunt / gettext / node.js application. I have generated pot files but how can I make my program translate automatically? I see you can upload them using pootle, zanata etc. but have not found enough online help with this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pootle or Zanata. But I'll tell you a way to translate it automatically based on user-agent once you have the translation files on .json format.

You can have a Lang service in angular like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5nhttcf/

```
module.factory('Lang',['$q', '$http', function($q){
    var lang = {};

    lang.literals = {};
    lang.current = navigator.language;
    lang.getLiterals = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(location.origin + "/getlang/"+lang.current).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if(data){
                lang.literals = data;
                deferred.resolve();
            }           
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return lang;

}
}]);
```

First, you call getLiterals when initialising the application.

Then, you just need to inject the factory in the controller and assign the literals to a local variable. Then in html you have a reference to localized literals:

```
<div> {{literals.greetings}} </div>
```

Note: I did not test the code, use only as a reference

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how the words get translated

Comment: The app doesn't translate the strings, just gets one language's strings or the others.  

Imagine this situation:  
  
In the app:  
lang.greetings - (A string that welcomes the user)  
  
In the server:  
lang/en.json  
lang/es.json  
  
en.json:  
{  
"greetings": "Hello user!"  
}  

es.json:  
{  
"greetings": "Hola usuario!"  
}  
  
So, when the app initializes, this Lang service gets the user's language strings. That way, Where in the app you wrote {{lang.greetings}} You'll see instead the string translated.  
  
If you still don't understand I can try to make a fiddle

Comment: Yes I understand how to do that but my question is how can I get those Strings translated automatically and then update the json language files?